# How do you proof {¬C, (¬C → ¬A), G} ∴ (A v ¬G) v ¬C using Fitch?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

{¬C, (¬C → ¬A), G} ∴ (A v ¬G) v ¬C

I'm having trouble introducing negation for ¬A to get to A and for G to get to ¬G.

[image: This is how far I got]

Thank you!

Comment: You are trying to derive $(A\vee\neg G)\vee\neg C$ from $\neg C$ and two red herrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over complicating things.

To derive a disjunction you either: (1) derive one of the disjuncts and use disjunction introduction, or (2) use an indirect proof.

Here, the first route is the way to go, but you have been trying to derive the *wrong* disjunct.

Do *not* try to derive $A\vee\neg G$.

---

$\neg C$ is one of the premises.

Disjunction introduction will immediately derive $(A\vee\neg G)\vee\neg C$.

Done!

Comment: I understand that since ¬C is a premise, I can introduce disjunction to derive (A v ¬G) v ¬C. But if I do not try to derive (A v ¬G), then how can I get this disjunct from the premises (¬C → ¬A) and G?

Comment: There is no compulsion to reference all premises in the proof.  You do *not need* to derive *anything* from the other premises when you can derive *all that was to be shown* from the first premise alone. @JaesonKim

Answer (score 0):

Note that by associativity, $((A \lor \neg G) \lor \neg C) \iff (A \lor (\neg G \lor \neg C))$

By disjunctive addition, we have $\neg G \lor \neg C $

By disjunctive addition again, we have $A \lor (\neg G \lor \neg C)$

Thus, associativity, we have $(A \lor \neg G) \lor \neg C$

Comment: Or... just *immediately* derive $(A\vee\neg G)\vee\neg C$ from $\neg C$ by disjunction introduction.  (The introduced disjunct may be a compound clause. You are not limited to literals or their negations.)